# Why "c:forEach" loop returns nothing in this jsp?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp

This should have been easy. I created `c:forEach` loop in my jsp page. This loop should display the objects that were extracted by my Service class from the db. Service class extracts the List correctly and the List in not empty. So the problem should be in my jsp page. When creating this jsp I followed the tutorial and that's why I don't understand what is not working here.
Here is it:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link
    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/poem-list.css"
    rel="stylesheet" />
<title>Poem Collection</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="maincontainer">
                <p>Poems</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="contentcolumn">
            <form method="GET">
                <table align="center">
                    <!-- tbody -->
                    <c:forEach var="poem" items="${poems}">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p class="title">${poem.title}</p>
                                <p class="annotation">by DUMMY<br> 
                                    written in ${poem.date}<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/collection.html">
                                <input type="button" class="view" value="View" />
                                </a>
                                </p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                    <!-- /tbody-->
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="bottom-footer">
            <p>My Collection</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller that displays collection and invokes `poem-list.jsp` with `forEach` loop.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/collection")
public ModelAndView collectionPage() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("poem-list");
    List<Poem> poems = poemService.getPoems();
    modelAndView.addObject("poems", poems);
    return new ModelAndView("poem-list");
}
```

And my Service class that extracts data from db:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Poem> getPoems() {
    return getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Poem").list();
}
```

Comment: would you give the code of your controller, so we can see how you are setting the `poem` object ?

Comment: its a pretty safe bet that no poems are returned from servlet/controller

Comment: Controller code from where you return this jsp as model can help.

Comment: Did you have proper getter setter method of Poem object?

Comment: do poems.size() in controller ;  it should be > 0

Comment: @vbera setters and getters were autogenerated, so I think Poem has them all.

Comment: @pramod.nikam.dev No errors in console, `poem.size()` shows `5`, so all is extracted ok. It just my `/collection.html` page is empty, I see that css has been applied, but no table with poems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In you controller you are instantiating the `ModelAndView modelAndView` but returning another instance:

```
return new ModelAndView("poem-list");
```

replace it with:

```
return modelAndView;
```

and it should work

Answer (score 1):

Most common cause is that `poems` are not set in any scope.

Please validate it using below code:

```
<c:if test="${poems ==null || poems.size()==0}">Poems are not found</c:if>
```